# How to prove that the discriminant is a symmetric function?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, discriminant

My approach:

We know that the discriminant for a polynomial $x^n - s_1x^n-1 + s_2x^n-2 + ...$ where $s_i$ is the elementary symmetric function.

is $(u_1-u_2)^2 (u_1-u_3)^2 ... (u_{n-1} - u_{n})^2$

So we want to show that this expression does not vary under interchanging terms.

We see that these terms consist of pairwise combinations of $u_1, ...u_n$
so it cannot vary when we change the order of arguments.

I don't think that's formal enough though. Is it the right track?

Comment: Why do you think it is not *formal enough*? Every permutation is generated by transpositions, hence if something is invariant with respect to every transposition, it is also invariant with respect to every permutation, i.e. it is a symmetric function.

Comment: If you transpose $u_i$ and $u_j$, the factors of the discriminant clearly just get rearranged, except for the $(u_i -u_j)^2$ term. Since this term is invariant under the transposition the discriminant is invariant under the transposition.

Comment: oh okay, I looked at some solutions and they used cyclotomic polynomials to prove it, so I thought I was completely off. Thanks though!!

Comment: It suffices to observe that the discriminant can be written as $$\prod_{\{i,j\}\in T}(u_i-u_j)^2,$$ where $T$ is the set of subsets of cardinal two of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the set of transpositions generates the whole symmetric group $S_n$, it suffices to show that swapping two $u_i$'s will not change the value in question.  So if the value is fixed under any transposition, then it's also fixed under any permutation of the $u_i$'s.

Suppose we want to interchange $u_j$ and $u_k$.  Notice that for $u_j$, there exists a term in the product that looks like $(u_j - u_m)^2$ or $(u_m - u_j)^2$ for all $1 \leq m \neq j \leq n$, and likewise for $u_k$.  So exchanging them won't change the value of the overall product since we will still have a term that looks like $(u_j - u_m)$ or $(u_m - u_j)$ for each $m \neq j$ (and likewise for $u_k$).  The only potential worry is a sign change due to the subtractions, but this is no problem because $(u_j - u_m)^2 = (u_m - u_j)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the discriminant can be written as 
$$
\prod_{\{i,j\}\in T}(u_i-u_j)^2,
$$ 
where $T$ is the set of subsets of cardinal two of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and it is equally clear that this product is invariant under permutation.